# Pushing to an array in a separate JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Lets say I have a JSON file, with an array inside of that JSON file.

```
{
"users": ["288381238123", "12312123123"]
}
```

Now I want to push to that array, and I have that file required at the top

```
const userList = require('../rolecall.json');
```

Then I have some other code here, which is seemingly supposed to push to that array

```
const users = userList.users;
users.push('82313123');
```

Now when I check back to the JSON file, there is no addition to the array. Why is that? If anyone could help me, that would be great.

Comment: You've only pushed to your local `users` variable. If you want the `.json` file to update, you'll need to write back to that file.

Comment: `require` just reads the file. you would need to us `fs.writeFile` to save new file contents

Comment: `fs.writeFile` works, but it requires to have Node.js installed

Comment: Yup, fs.writeFile worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

When you 'push' to the array in Javascript, you are only changing the Javascript object.

**Edit: taking Lyon's comment into account**

The short answer is, you can't change a file on the client machine using javascript. That would be a **huge** security issue (though it used to be possible, fun times).

However, you can [ask the browser to display a save dialog](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server) asking the user whether they want to save the content of your json to a file.

**Old answer**

If you want to save the changes to a file located on the server, you need to send the informations to said server, preferably via a POST request.

A simple way to do it is to use [Ajax requests](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp).
You can use the `JSON.stringify` method to format your `users` object.

```
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(users));
```

Then you can handle the request on the server. The way to do that depends on the language used (PHP, Ruby, Node, etc)

Comment: The file is currently stored locally on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

**Observations :**

- You are pushing a element into a local array `userList`. If you want to update the `rolecall.json` file, you'll need to write back to that file.
- Javascript (client side) has not functionality to create, edit etc.. files.You can do it in back-end side.

**Workaround :**

You got your json in `userList` constant variable. now you can push that element into the array and then write back to `rolecall.json` if you're manipulating it in your backend (ie.: NodeJs)

```js
const userList = {
"users": ["288381238123", "12312123123"]
};

userList.users.push('82313123');

console.log(userList);
```

In `node.js` you can use the `fs` library.

```
fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile('fileName.json', JSON.stringify(userList));
```